# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'gdbm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, devops

Пытаюсь начать работать в докер ([Установка на Ubuntu](http://docker.crank.ru/docs/docker-engine/install/on-linux-distributions/installation-on-ubuntu/)).

Завис вот на этой команде
Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 (LTS)

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

возвращает

> ModuleNotFound 'gdbm'

при том, что я их уже установил через `sudo apt-get`.

Одновременно с этим, попытка написать:

```
python-gdbm -V
```

или

```
python3-gdbm -V
```

или

```
python-gdbm --version
```

возвращают тот же *ModuleNotFound*.

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: `deb ...` — это не команда, а описание репозитория, которое рекомендуют вписать в файл `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`. p.s. и руководствоваться всё-таки лучше не левыми сайтами, а [официальной инструкцией](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простой и быстрый вариант установки:

```
$ curl -fsSL get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
$ sudo sh get-docker.sh
```

[Скрипт сделает](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-ce-1) все необходимые манипуляции за вас. Останется только добавить **вашего пользователя** (из-под которого вы работаете) в группу `docker`. **Допустим**, что ваш пользователь `ubuntu`:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker ubuntu
```

> Если вдруг  `curl` не установлен, то перед загрузкой скрипта установите его: `$ sudo apt-get install curl -y`